# How to make your bot ask for permissions before joining a server discord.py

Tags: discord.py

So I have great bot with lots of functionality that I'm planning to launch. The thing is, I need to have permissions like administrator on before it join, without the server owner having to create a bot role with administrator permissions. I need something like carl-bot or mee6 when they are invited to your server, they ask you for administrator permissions befoer joining.[image]

I want something like this to appear. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, go to the OAuth tab of the developer portal:

[image: OAuth tab]

Next, make the scope "bot":

[image: "Bot" scope]

Thirdly, switch on all the permissions you need:

[image: Permissions section]

Finally, copy the invite link from the scopes section:

[image: Invite link]